# Is it possible to implement SSO using LDAP in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, joomla2.5

I realize that Joomla supports LDAP but I don't want my entire database moved over to the Joomla database (for obvious reasons). I was hoping to implement SSO to maybe prevent this from happening. Is this possible? I can't find any good information on it online, after a couple of days of googling and reading different articles. I think maybe JAuthTools might be able to help me do it but even with the wiki surrounding that extension I can't find any good information on it's SSO support. If anyone knows how to do this that would be great. The users are currently stored in Active Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAuthTools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/158) as far as I'm aware isn't actively maintained anymore, and was for Joomla! 1.5.

The last SSO integration we did was with [JMapMyLDAP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-cloud-based/18108) and it seemed to work pretty well and it's last update was less than a month ago.